# must have a string value or be of a type which implements IRouteConstraint

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc

I have a controller with the following action:

```
    public ActionResult Post(int pId)
    {
        urlPostTitle = "Hello";
        pId=23;
        return RedirectPermanent(Url.Action("PostRedirect", new { pId = pId, postTitle = urlPostTitle }));
    }
```

And my Route as:

```
routes.MapRoute("GetPostRedirect", "{pId}/{postTitle}", new { controller = "Blog", action = "PostRedirect", }, new { pId = @"^\d{1,3}$", postTitle = UrlParameter.Optional });
```

But I am getting this error on `return RedirectPermanent` line:

```
The constraint entry 'postTitle' on the route with URL '{pId}/{postTitle}' must have a string value or be of a type which implements IRouteConstraint.
```

I am unable to understand the cause the error as `urlPostTitle` is alreay a string, please help me out solving this error.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have things a little mixed up.  Try this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "GetPostRedirect",
    "{pId}/{postTitle}",
    new { controller = "Blog", action = "PostRedirect", postTitle = UrlParameter.Optional },
    new { pId = @"^\d{1,3}$" });
```

This:

```
new { controller = "Blog", action = "PostRedirect", postTitle = UrlParameter.Optional }
```

is specifying the default values for each of the parameters, whereas this:

```
new { pId = @"^\d{1,3}$" }
```

is specifying the constraints which dictate the values your parameters are allowed to take on.

Newer versions of MVC (4 and above) actually use [Named Arguments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx) in order to make the distinction clearer.  So the code above would become:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "GetPostRedirect",
    url: "{pId}/{postTitle}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Blog", action = "PostRedirect", postTitle = UrlParameter.Optional },
    constraints: new { pId = @"^\d{1,3}$" });
```